# swift sprite kit - if and switch case not working properly

Tags: swift, switch-statement, textures, case

I've been trying to make this work for a few days now and I don't understand what's wrong with my code. I'm trying to display the score of the player. I have two sprite labels, one for the 1st number, one for the 2nd number. The problem is that the second number doesn't change when the number is supposed to be 1, 2 or 7. It works for the other numbers but doesn't for only these, it doesn't make any sense.

If you can't see a problem in my code can you suggest a different way to do this so I can pass over this error?

```
//scoreVA is the current level/10 
//scoreVB is the number that the first node should have
//scoreVC is the number that the second node should have

var scoreVA = 0.0
var scoreVB = 0.0
var scoreVC = 0.0
```

This the first function for the first 9 levels and the first number

```
func setLevelLabel(){
        let Number0Icon = SKTexture(imageNamed: "0numbericon.png")
        Number0Icon.filteringMode = .Nearest
        let Number1Icon = SKTexture(imageNamed: "1numbericon.png")
        Number1Icon.filteringMode = .Nearest
        let Number2Icon = SKTexture(imageNamed: "2numbericon.png")
        Number2Icon.filteringMode = .Nearest
        let Number3Icon = SKTexture(imageNamed: "3numbericon.png")
        Number3Icon.filteringMode = .Nearest
        let Number4Icon = SKTexture(imageNamed: "4numbericon.png")
        Number4Icon.filteringMode = .Nearest
        let Number5Icon = SKTexture(imageNamed: "5numbericon.png")
        Number5Icon.filteringMode = .Nearest
        let Number6Icon = SKTexture(imageNamed: "6numbericon.png")
        Number6Icon.filteringMode = .Nearest
        let Number7Icon = SKTexture(imageNamed: "7numbericon.png")
        Number7Icon.filteringMode = .Nearest
        let Number8Icon = SKTexture(imageNamed: "8numbericon.png")
        Number8Icon.filteringMode = .Nearest
        let Number9Icon = SKTexture(imageNamed: "9numbericon.png")
        Number9Icon.filteringMode = .Nearest

        let changeLeveNumberLabel0 = SKAction.setTexture:resize:(Number0Icon, resize: true)
        let changeLeveNumberLabel1 = SKAction.setTexture:resize:(Number1Icon, resize: true)
        let changeLeveNumberLabel2 = SKAction.setTexture:resize:(Number2Icon, resize: true)
        let changeLeveNumberLabel3 = SKAction.setTexture:resize:(Number3Icon, resize: true)
        let changeLeveNumberLabel4 = SKAction.setTexture:resize:(Number4Icon, resize: true)
        let changeLeveNumberLabel5 = SKAction.setTexture:resize:(Number5Icon, resize: true)
        let changeLeveNumberLabel6 = SKAction.setTexture:resize:(Number6Icon, resize: true)
        let changeLeveNumberLabel7 = SKAction.setTexture:resize:(Number7Icon, resize: true)
        let changeLeveNumberLabel8 = SKAction.setTexture:resize:(Number8Icon, resize: true)
        let changeLeveNumberLabel9 = SKAction.setTexture:resize:(Number9Icon, resize: true)
        if(level == 1){
            _levelNumberLabel.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel1)}
        else if(level == 2){
            _levelNumberLabel.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel2)}
        else if(level == 3){
            _levelNumberLabel.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel3)}
        else if(level == 4){
            _levelNumberLabel.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel4)}
        else if(level == 5){
            _levelNumberLabel.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel5)}
        else if(level == 6){
            _levelNumberLabel.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel6)}
        else if(level == 7){
            _levelNumberLabel.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel7)}
        else if(level == 8){
            _levelNumberLabel.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel8)}
        else if(level == 9){
            _levelNumberLabel.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel9)}
        else if(level >= 10){
            _levelNumberLabel2.hidden = false
            scoreVA = Double(level) / 10
            scoreVB = floor(scoreVA)
            scoreVC = ((scoreVA - floor(scoreVA)) * 10)

            if(scoreVB == 1){
                _levelNumberLabel.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel1)
            } else if(scoreVB == 2){
                _levelNumberLabel.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel2)
                _levelNumberLabel2.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.7 + _levelLabel.frame.size.width/2 + _levelNumberLabel.frame.size.width + 5
                    , self.frame.size.height * 0.9)
            }
            else if(scoreVB == 3){
                _levelNumberLabel.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel3)
            } else if(scoreVB == 4){
                _levelNumberLabel.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel4)
            } else if(scoreVB == 5){
                _levelNumberLabel.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel5)
            } else if(scoreVB == 6){
                _levelNumberLabel.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel6)
            } else if(scoreVB == 7){
                _levelNumberLabel.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel7)
            } else if(scoreVB == 8){
                _levelNumberLabel.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel8)
            } else if(scoreVB == 9){
                _levelNumberLabel.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel9)}

            setLevelLabel2()
            }}
```

This the second function for the second number that doesn't work properly

```
    func setLevelLabel2(){
        // Number textures
        let Number0Icon = SKTexture(imageNamed: "0numbericon.png")
        Number0Icon.filteringMode = .Nearest
        let Number1Icon = SKTexture(imageNamed: "1numbericon.png")
        Number1Icon.filteringMode = .Nearest
        let Number2Icon = SKTexture(imageNamed: "2numbericon.png")
        Number2Icon.filteringMode = .Nearest
        let Number3Icon = SKTexture(imageNamed: "3numbericon.png")
        Number3Icon.filteringMode = .Nearest
        let Number4Icon = SKTexture(imageNamed: "4numbericon.png")
        Number4Icon.filteringMode = .Nearest
        let Number5Icon = SKTexture(imageNamed: "5numbericon.png")
        Number5Icon.filteringMode = .Nearest
        let Number6Icon = SKTexture(imageNamed: "6numbericon.png")
        Number6Icon.filteringMode = .Nearest
        let Number7Icon = SKTexture(imageNamed: "7numbericon.png")
        Number7Icon.filteringMode = .Nearest
        let Number8Icon = SKTexture(imageNamed: "8numbericon.png")
        Number8Icon.filteringMode = .Nearest
        let Number9Icon = SKTexture(imageNamed: "9numbericon.png")
        Number9Icon.filteringMode = .Nearest

        let changeLeveNumberLabel0 = SKAction.setTexture:resize:(Number0Icon, resize: true)
        let changeLeveNumberLabel1 = SKAction.setTexture:resize:(Number1Icon, resize: true)
        let changeLeveNumberLabel2 = SKAction.setTexture:resize:(Number2Icon, resize: true)
        let changeLeveNumberLabel3 = SKAction.setTexture:resize:(Number3Icon, resize: true)
        let changeLeveNumberLabel4 = SKAction.setTexture:resize:(Number4Icon, resize: true)
        let changeLeveNumberLabel5 = SKAction.setTexture:resize:(Number5Icon, resize: true)
        let changeLeveNumberLabel6 = SKAction.setTexture:resize:(Number6Icon, resize: true)
        let changeLeveNumberLabel7 = SKAction.setTexture:resize:(Number7Icon, resize: true)
        let changeLeveNumberLabel8 = SKAction.setTexture:resize:(Number8Icon, resize: true)
        let changeLeveNumberLabel9 = SKAction.setTexture:resize:(Number9Icon, resize: true)

        lastnumb = Int(floor(scoreVC))

        switch(lastnumb){
        case 0..<1:
            _levelNumberLabel2.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel0)
        case 1..<2:
            _levelNumberLabel2.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel1)
        case 2..<3:
            _levelNumberLabel2.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel2)
        case 3..<4:
            _levelNumberLabel2.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel3)
        case 4..<5:
            _levelNumberLabel2.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel4)
        case 5..<6:
            _levelNumberLabel2.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel5)
        case 6..<7:
            _levelNumberLabel2.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel6)
        case 7..<8:
            _levelNumberLabel2.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel7)
        case 8..<9:
            _levelNumberLabel2.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel8)
        case 9..<10:
            _levelNumberLabel2.runAction(changeLeveNumberLabel9)
        default:
            break
        }


    }
```

Comment: Is that code working with the `SKAction.setTexture:resize:()` in it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you're doing a lot more work than you need to. I think refactoring your function would probably help here:

```
func setLevelLabel2() {
    lastnumb = Int(floor(scoreVC))
    println("lastnumb: \(lastnumb)") // is this the right number?

    let icon = SKTexture(imageNamed: "\(lastnumb)numbericon.png")
    icon.filteringMode = .Nearest

    let action = SKAction.setTexture(icon, resize: true)

    _levelNumberLabel2.runAction(action)
}
```

In general, you don't want to rely on floating-point values (even double-precision) to hold integers. They're nearly always off by a tiny bit, so equality comparisons can fail and `floor` can give you a different value than you expect.

Comment: I'm amazed on how you made that code so small. Now it seems it's not working on number 3 and 4. I think that finding another way to get scoreVC will make it work.

Comment: The sprite just doesn't change texture, I made the value of scoreVC visible with a label text and I can see it go to 3 but the score label stays at 2, it pretty much jumps from 2 to 5 and doesn't change to 3 and 4 when it's supposed to